# Count How Many Rows Inserted From Last SQL Query

Tags: mysql

I have this query :

```
INSERT INTO db1.outbox (DestinationNumber, TextDecoded)
SELECT User.CellPhone, '$SMSMessage' as TextDecoded
FROM db2.User
WHERE User.PurchaseDate BETWEEN 2012-01-01 AND 2012-01-31
```

it does multiple rows insertion to 'outbox' table. but I don't know how many rows inserted. how to have number of rows inserted from that SQL syntax? thanks.

**update**
I got '-1' as result of this command :

```
$insertedRows = mysql_query("SELECT ROW_COUNT()");
$rowInserted = mysql_fetch_array($insertedRows);
$rowInserted = $rowInserted[0];
echo $rowInserted;
```

but I see there are 27 rows inserted on my table. what did I do wrong?

Comment: The reason "SELECT ROW_COUNT()" does not work for you is that your query is no longer the most recent query by the time PHP returns control to you.  Mysql returns -1 because PHP has invoked already "SELECT ROW_COUNT()" and "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()".  After selecting an information function, the result of "ROW_COUNT()" is -1.  That's why you needed to use the special PHP variable '''mysql_affected_rows''', which cached the value from "SELECT ROW_COUNT()" after it executed your query.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

put this on your last statement;

```
SELECT ROW_COUNT();
```

**UPDATE 1**

how about using **[`mysql_affected_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php)**, example

```
<?php

   $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
   if (!$link) 
   {
       die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }
   mysql_select_db('mydb');

   /* this should return the correct numbers of deleted records */
   mysql_query('you SQL QUERY HERE');
   printf("Records deleted: %d\n", mysql_affected_rows());

?>
```

Comment: I just tried to use ROW_COUNT() function, but gives me -1 as result. in fact, I have 27 rows inserted. see my update of this post above.

Comment: @RobertHanson oh i see that you are using `PHP`, try using `mysql_affected_rows()` as seen on this PHP manual, http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php

Comment: @RobertHanson you're welcome! oh by the way, next time use `PDO` or `MySQLI` since your current code is vulnerable with sql injection.

Comment: got it bro... I have a plan to rewrite my code after everything is done. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some possibilities:

» If you have an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column, you can fetch the row number before and after insert

» `SELECT ROW_COUNT()` returns the number of rows changed, deleted, or inserted by the last statement if it was an `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, or `INSERT` ([doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count))

» You can use `mysqli_affected_rows` (since `mysql_` functions are being deprecated) to get the number of affected rows in a previous MySQL operation ([doc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php))

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

if (!$link) {
    printf("Can't connect to localhost. Error: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/* Insert rows */
mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (1)");
printf("Affected rows (INSERT): %d\n", mysqli_affected_rows($link));
```